# Updating Only a Few Properties in a Context - EF4 Sequence Contains No Elements Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I am trying to update 2 fields (Comments and DateFolluwUpResponse) in a single record but when I do so, I am getting an exception:

```
Sequence contains no elements
```

I am following the example in Julia Lerman's DbContext book in section "Changing Existing Entities"

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FollowUp(FollowUpViewModel m)
{

   //Update record in Prospects

    int recordIdToUpdate = m.Prospect.id;
    string followUpComments = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Prospect.Comments) ? m.Prospect.Comments : String.Empty);
    DateTime followUpDate = DateTime.Now;

    //Update record
    using (var context = new LocatorContext()){

        //---------------------------------------
        //Exception happens here

        var followUpUpdate = (from p in context.Prospects where p.id == recordIdToUpdate select p).Single();

       //----------------------------------------

        followUpUpdate.Comments = followUpComments;
        followUpUpdate.DateFollowUpResponse = followUpDate;

        context.SaveChanges();

    }


    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `Single` throws an Exception because the query returns no values.